# Sentence stress: "It was awful."

Tags: pronunciation, word-stress

I would like to know the normal pattern of sentence stress for this sentence:

> It was awful.

Here is my idea:

1. The stress is on the first syllable of the adjective *awful*.
2. As long as we don't shift stress for special meaning the verb *was* is unstressed.

Is my idea correct? Is it the same for similar sentences?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Again, these kind of "amirite" questions are not really helpful for the community. Instead of posting all as a question and asking "am I right?", please consider writing a self-answer and explaining the connotation that the stressing conveys, optimally with resources and the "why"s.

Comment: The `english` tag, and similar, should not be used. *Everything here* is about English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your explanation is a bit confusing to me, but it's like this:

> ***It*** was awful.

Emphasizing that we are talking about *it* opposed to something else.

> It ***was*** awful.

Emphasizing that it *was* awful, but implying that it is no longer awful. Or, this says it was awful despite some reservations.

> It was ***aw*ful**. (Stress on "aw")

Emphasizing that it was *awful* opposed to some other description. This would be the most common form.

Comment: I agree with all of your forms but I'd put the emphasis solely on the "aw" of awful. *It was **aw**ful.*

Comment: @Catija agreed. Updated answer

Comment: Good answer, people seem to like it.  All fine, except that I wouldn't characterize "*It **was** awful." as "implying that it is no longer awful*".  I hear "*was*" stressed most often as an argumentative reply to "It wasn't that bad...", basically analogous to a childish reply "was, too!"

Comment: @VictorBazarov agreed. Updated answer